# How to return pdf from byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to get a pdf file from an array byte

```
[HttpGet("DownloadFile")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetPdf()
{
    fileByte = await _context.CvFiles.Where(m => m.IdCandidat == 32 && m.Id == 37).Select(m => m.FileContent).FirstAsync();
   var fileName = await _context.CvFiles.Where(m => m.IdCandidat == 32 && m.Id == 37).Select(m => m.NameFile).FirstAsync();

    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    HttpResponseMessage objResponse = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    objResponse.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileByte);
    objResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    objResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
    objResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

    return objResponse;
}
```

When this method gets called, I am not getting an pdf back at all. Here is the response I am receiving:

```
{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":["attachment; filename=CV-Marzouk.pdf"]},{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/pdf"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":null,"method":{"method":"GET"},"requestUri":null,"headers":[],"properties":{}},"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

Why am I not getting the pdf back as part of the request? How can that be resolved?

Comment: You should be using the `Request` property rather than creating a new `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: To get a pdf file from an array byte You can use this:-

byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.pdf");


System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.pdf", bytes);

Comment: If you have the right array of bytes, then you can just use this `return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");`